# Unique list of lists

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

I have a nested list as an example:

```
lst_a = [[1,2,3,5], [1,2,3,7], [1,2,3,9], [1,2,6,8]]
```

I'm trying to check if the first 3 indices of a nested list element are the same as other.

I.e.

if [1,2,3] exists in other lists, remove all the other nested list elements that contain that. So that the nested list is unique.

I'm not sure the most pythonic way of doing this would be.

```
for i in range(0, len(lst_a)):
    if lst[i][:3] == lst[i-1][:3]:
         lst[i].pop()
```

Desired output:

```
lst_a = [[1,2,3,9], [1,2,6,8]]
```

Comment: Think of the sequence - you check `list[0]` with `list[len(list)-1]`, then `list[1]` with `list[0]` an delete one item from `list[1]`, so list[1] = [2,3,7] and now you check `list[2]` with [2,3,7], do you really want that?

Comment: Are you sure, the code does work the way you intended? Also, generally it is bad idea to modify list while iterating through it. What should be the desired output of your code?

Comment: It doesnt work as intended no... I need a better way of doing it.

Comment: Can you please show the desired output?

Comment: Is the list sorted? In particular, are items with the same first three elements always next to each other?

Comment: List is not sorted. And yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you said in comments, sublists that have the same first three elements are always next to each other (but the list is not necessarily sorted) you can use `itertools.groupby` to group those elements and then get the `next` from each of the groups.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lst_a = [[1,2,3,5], [1,2,3,7], [1,2,3,9], [1,2,6,8]]
>>> [next(g) for k, g in groupby(lst_a, key=lambda x: x[:3])]
[[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 6, 8]]
```

Or use a list comprehension with `enumerate` and compare the current element with the last one:

```
>>> [x for i, x in enumerate(lst_a) if i == 0 or lst_a[i-1][:3] != x[:3]]
[[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 6, 8]]
```

This does not require any imports, but IMHO when using `groupby` it is much clearer what the code is supposed to do. Note, however, that unlike your method, both of those will create a *new* filtered list, instead of updating/deleting from the original list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a loop `For` if you want to check all possibilities. I guess it should like :

```
for i in range(0, len(lst_a)):
   for j in range(i, len(lst_a)):
      if lst[i][:3] == lst[j][:3]:
         lst[i].pop()
```

Deleting while going throught the list is maybe not the best idea you should delete unwanted elements at the end

Answer (score 0):

Going with your approach, Find the below code:

```
lst=[lst_a[0]]
for li in lst_a[1:]:
    if li[:3]!=lst[0][:3]:
        lst.append(li)
print(lst)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to filter a list:

```
dct = {tuple(i[:3]): i for i in lst}
# {(1, 2, 3): [1, 2, 3, 9], (1, 2, 6): [1, 2, 6, 8]}

list(dct.values())
# [[1, 2, 3, 9], [1, 2, 6, 8]]
```